# OpenCV + CodeBlocks : error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, opencv, codeblocks, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run a simple Display Image C++ program on CodeBlocks integrated with OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie. The program builds properly but during run it gives me the following error  error while loading shared libraries: cv2.so: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory. Could somebody help me resolve this?

P.S : I have read through a few similar posts but the solution didn't help or I didn't execute them right. Could somebody provide a stepwise instruction. I am new to Linux and Pi.

Comment: I am guessing open CV hasn't been installed properly meaning the shared objects (so files) havent been copied into the right folders where the linux loader searches when trying to locate dependencies.
see the instructions here to check if the  missing cv2.so file can be located 
`http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120015/how-to-find-out-the-dynamic-libraries-executables-loads-when-run`
It would be helpful to know how you got code blocks running on raspbian jessie. I normally use stripped down version of raspbian and therefore unaware if comes prebundled which I suspect is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. But I found a work around by pasting the files into the project folder.

Comment: No Raspbian Jessie doesn't come pre-bundled with codeblocks. I installed it directly from the repository.